# Read line/variable from text file javascript

Tags: javascript, text, line

So I've been playing around with a media player that uses javascript to choose which file to play, I was wondering if i could have an external file that has the video file names in it, and the javascript will just read one line and use that as the current video to play?

my current JS lines that chooses which video files to play is this:

```
playMovie('http://URL.tld/videos/videoFile.flv');
```

Now this works fine, but instead of having to edit this all the time I'd like to just edit a text file and have it something like this:

```
playMovie('http://URL.tld/videos/'+fileName+'.flv');
```

but instead of just being a variable, it'll be a line from a text file.

Thanks

Comment: JavsScript runs on the client side. To do what you're describing, JavaScript would need to be able to read files on the client's machine and if JavaScript could do that there would be all sorts of security problems.

Comment: Can't it read a text file off of a server, if i was to specify a URL?

Comment: Via AJAX JavaScript can retrieve data from a file on a server, yes. Off the client, no.

Comment: Where is that file? On the server or on the client side?

Comment: It's on the server, Im going to try AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You can't read files with javascript, but you can send ajax calls to a server page that can.

Comment: would it be possible to read a file with PHP, then store the line of text in a variable?

Comment: Yes, with ajax you make a call to a webpage and that webpage returns information.